# cudnnがインストールされていることを確認する方法

Tags: linux, cuda, debian, gpu

cudnnについて、以下の３点を知りたいです。

- cudnnが正常にインストールされていることを確認する方法
- インストールされているcudnnのバージョンの確認
- 下記のようにdpkgコマンドでcudnnをインストールしたときに、/usr/local/cuda以下にcudnnのファイルが置かれるかどうか

  - https://qiita.com/JeJeNeNo/items/a56be3be69dc88e6dfa4#cudnn-71%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg -l`と実行するとシステムにインストールされているパッケージの一覧が表示されるので、`cudnn`をキーワードに`grep`をかけてみましょう。一覧の中にパッケージのバージョンも一緒に表示されるはずです。

```
$ dpkg -l | grep "cudnn"
```

インストールされているパッケージ名を確認できたら、今度は`dpkg -L <Package Name>`でパッケージによってインストールされたファイルの一覧を確認できます。

```
$ dpkg -L <Package Name>
```